# Trying to install mod_proxy in Apache-Httpd-2.2.15

Tags: linux, redhat, httpd, mod-proxy, tomcat6

I have spent the afternoon trying to install the mod_proxy module into apache.

I have tried

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/apache2 --enable-proxy --enable-proxy-http

./configure --prefix=/opt/apache2 --enable-module=proxy
```

After it finishes installing, navigating to /opt/apache2/modules only shows one file: httpd.exp.

It seems that the module is not being installed.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason why you didn't take the current SRPM, replace the tarball, and rebuild? `mod_proxy` seems to be standard in the package.

Comment: Further, there's very few sane reasons to rebuild apache these days, the distributions packages on the major distributions are very good, and they'll get the security updates you're likely to forget.

Answer (score 1):

`./configure --enable-proxy=static` will build `mod_proxy` linked statically into the resulting `httpd` executable; this is the default if you specify `./configure --enable-proxy`.  `./configure --enable-proxy=shared` is necessary to build the module as a loadable shared library.

Similarly, `./configure --enable-modules=proxy` will link `mod_proxy` statically into the executable, while `./configure --enable-mods-shared=proxy` will cause it to be built as a shared library.  See the Apache [configure](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/configure.html) documentation for more details.